# Installing rhostudio gems on osxlion gives "please install build tools"

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rhomobile, rhodes

I installed rhostudio but I can't seem to install the gems using the provided scripts.
I get

Last login: Sat Mar 24 13:43:13 on ttys001
jay-pc:~ mac$ /Volumes/RhoInstaller/Install\ gems ; exit;
Please install building tools
logout

I'm a new ruby dev...

I don't know if this is referring to java or make etc. Or something ruby or gems specific.
I have jdk installed as I use the machine for java development.

Comment: It probably wants you to install the dev tools for Mac OSX. https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/. It also needs to have the Java JDK installed, which is a separate download for Mac Lion.

Comment: Thanks - JDK is installed - I've been doing java development on the machine. I'll try the dev tools. Edit: I don't think you need xcode - it comes with its own ide on eclipse. Is it possible it's something missing in ruby?

Comment: Yep birryree - I installed gcc and that did it! thanks so much. gcc link is here if you don't want xcode: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay yes - birryree mentioned above that xcode is needed. This is the answer. It's actually the Gnu Compiler Collection that is required so if you don't care about getting xcode you can just download the osx GCC from here to save some bandwidth:

(lion here too)
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer